# How do I make Skyrim run smooth and stable with a high "uGridsToLoad" setting?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it possible to have a stable '[uGridsToLoad](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Skyrim#Tweak_rendering_distance)' setting at 11 or 13? If so, do you have any tips on what I can do to ensure that 'uGridsToLoad' runs as smooth as possible?

Comment: I edited out the part asking about what hardware do people use as this could be seen as a [shopping recommendation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), which is causing some users to vote to [close this question as off-topic](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/close/80538).

Comment: best solution is to upgrade your hardware.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [Skyrim Script Extender (SKSE)](http://skse.silverlock.org/) installed, add the ff. lines to `\Skyrim\Data\SKSE\skse.ini` (create the 'skse.ini' file using a text editor if it does not exist):

```
[Memory]
DefaultHeapInitialAllocMB=768
ScrapHeapSizeMB=256
```

or just download and install this skse.ini config file: [SKSE ini pre-download for lazy users](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/51038/?).

This will help improve performance and stability at higher uGridsToLoad settings than the default.

The above feature by SKSE was originally part of the [Skyrim Startup Memory Editor (SSME)](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/50305/?) mod. From SSME's FAQ:

> Q: What does this do?
>   A: Sheson discovered that if you make Skyrim
>   allocate more memory initially, it prevents crashes that occur later
>   when that first allocated chunk runs out and Skyrim allocates a second
>   chunk. SSME aims to be a very simple way to patch Skyrim so it
>   allocates more memory.

**[CTD and Memory patch ENBoost](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/38649/?)** should also help. It helps Skyrim better utilize video and system memory, preventing CTDs and increasing performance.